# Calling a Rails function via a POST

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, http-post

I am trying to convert a php script to a ruby script that lives inside a RoR app. This is being done from a Javascript block that is outside the RoR app. I have had success calling a function within the RoR app via a GET but I would like to do it using a POST.

That is to say, this works:

```
function foo() {
    var uri = "http://localhost:3000/foo/bar?thing1=654&thing2=what";           
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("get", uri, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This does not:

```
function foo() {
    var uri = "http://localhost:3000/foo/bar";
    var params = "thing1=654&thing2=what";          
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("post", uri, true);
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

Is there something different I need to do to get this working with a POST?

The params that are actually getting passed into the controller are: {"controller"=>"foo", "action"=>"bar"}

**Update**

Oddly it looks like, based on firebug reports, that it isn't using POST but OPTIONS for some reason. Is there something wrong with the way I've written this?

Comment: Any chance of including the logs? One issue might be if you aren't include your authenticity token...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, as it turns out, on the live site the url I was pointing was *not* in the same domain. I had thought it was.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to send the correct Content-Type header.

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: Still seems to be sending the call but it doesn't have the params when it gets into the server. The params it is getting are: {"controller"=>"foo", "action"=>"bar"}

Comment: This is really odd, i'm currently trying it myself and when i add the content-type header it doesn't do the request at all.
If it does work for you try to add the following headers as well which might work:
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
Also, i don't know the limitations of the project but isn't it easier to use something like jQuery? this might fix it.

Comment: Hmm that sill doesn't seem to be doing it for it. Also tried using jQuery. $.post(uri, { thing1: "654", thing2: "what" } ); called but didn't send the params either.

Comment: Actually, I'm even able to simply remove post from that jquery call and switch it out for get and it works! Is there a setting somewhere in RoR apps that determine if POSTs can be made to them?

Comment: Well i think what you want to achieve can be done in the routing, here you can define if a certain action should accept post or get, if it doesn't match a 404 is rendered. Is this what you want?

Comment: Not exactly, it should accept post or get and if it is successful it just puts an entry into a database based on the params passed to it in the post or get.